# Unable to setup IBM Worklight on my mac

Tags: android, ios, eclipse-plugin, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using mac with OS 10.11.4, eclipse mars jee 64 bit & ADT

I'm trying to run the IBM mobilefirst plugin in eclipse mars, but it is not showing me in Create new project as image shown below.I have added all necessary plug ins successfully.

[image]

After installation of all plug in it is showing success as image shown below.

[image]

I'm loading the IBM mobilefirst from eclipse marketplace.

As I am new to hybrid application development please guide me to setup eclipse, IBM mobile first or worklight and ADT bundle plug in step-by-step.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you first need to read about the product before simply installing it...

In MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 things are **different**.
You create a standard **Cordova** application using the **Cordova CLI** and you add to it to MobileFirst SDK also using the Cordova CLI, because the SDK is made up of a set of **Cordova plug-ins**.

The Studio plug-in is now a tool that exposes **MobileFirst CLI** functionality in the UI, such as: loading the console, registering applications, previewing applications...

Read more about MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 here:

- https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/06/17/ibm-releases-next-generation-of-mobilefirst-foundation-built-for-hybrid-cloud/

And about the Studio plug-in here:

- https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/06/17/ibm-mobilefirst-studio-8-0-plugin-for-eclipse-now-available/

Also learn how to migrate your existing apps:

- https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/06/17/migrating-apps-and-adapters-to-mobilefirst-foundation-8-0/
- https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/upgrading/migration-cookbook/

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have seen tutorial for installing but cordova cli and mobile first cli is not mentioned anywhere.Anyways thanks for help.I will try and update you.upvoted for important information :)

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but I am stuck at downloading cordova plaform for iOS & android. It is showig me this error: Error: No platforms added to this project. Please use `cordova platform add <platform>` can you help me in this ? I have already added Android SDK.

Comment: Well, do what is says... navigate to the root of the Cordova project and run the command: "cordova platform add ios".

Comment: thanks it worked !! one last thing...now built successfully but it is showing me this error: 2016-07-30 09:34:47.609 instruments[9268:1431174] WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.
Instruments Usage Error: Unknown device specified: "B7257830-92A2-4C85-A4BA-342D7237F9A8"

Do you know where to change UDID of device in file? -name of file or file path ?